# C++ getting a seg fault before even entering a function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a problem where I try to compress a file's data. Everything works up to the compression call, but it isn't the compression call itself, as the segfault is thrown before it. Showing my code will make it much clearer:

```
std::cout << "FILENAME: ";
std::cin >> filename;

if(!fileExists(filename))
{
    std::cout << "ERR: FILE NOT FOUND." << std::endl;
    continue;
}

std::cout << "Compressing file data...";
writeFile(filename, zlib_compress(readFile(filename)));
std::cout << " Done." << std::endl;
```

At the function zlib_compress...

```
std::string zlib_compress(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << "DEBUG" << std::endl;

    z_stream zs;                        // z_stream is zlib's control structure
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

    if (deflateInit(&zs, 9) != Z_OK)
        std::cout << "deflateInit failed while compressing." << std::endl;

    zs.next_in = (Bytef*)str.data();
    zs.avail_in = str.size();           // set the z_stream's input

    int ret;
    char outbuffer[1073741824];
    std::string outstring;

    // retrieve the compressed bytes blockwise
    do
    {
        zs.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(outbuffer);
        zs.avail_out = sizeof(outbuffer);

        ret = deflate(&zs, Z_FINISH);

        if (outstring.size() < zs.total_out)
        {
            // append the block to the output string
            outstring.append(outbuffer, zs.total_out - outstring.size());
        }
    } while(ret == Z_OK);

    deflateEnd(&zs);

    if(ret != Z_STREAM_END) // an error occurred that was not EOF
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Exception during zlib compression: (" << ret << ") " << zs.msg;
        std::cout << oss.str();
    }

    return outstring;
}
```

I know, I know, that function needs work, I just C&P'd from somewhere to try it out.

But the thing is this:

`std::cout << "DEBUG" << std::endl;` is **never** called. The compiler says that the seg fault is coming from here:

```
  std::string zlib_compress(const std::string& str)
> {
```

But why...? It was working earlier. I just don't know what went wrong!

**Edit:** Debugger output.

```
#0 00000000 0x00402cbb in __chkstk_ms() (??:??)
#1 004013BE zlib_compress(str=...) (C:\Users\***\Documents\Work\Programming\Compressor\z.cpp:5)
#2 00401DDA _fu15___ZSt4cout() (C:\Users\***\Documents\Work\Programming\Compressor\main.cpp:80)
```

Comment: How is `filename` defined?

Comment: Before that code occurs, as `std::string filename;`

Comment: Can you run it through a debugger? What are you compiling with?

Comment: `std::cout << "Compressing file data...";` doesn't flush the output stream - you may not see it even if execution reaches the following line (`writeFile(filename, zlib_compress(readFile(filename)));`).  More generally, you should break your `writeFile(filename, zlib_compress(readFile(filename)));` line into three separate steps and see which one barfs.  You haven't posted `readFile()` source, so how can we check what you're providing `zlib_compress`?

Comment: I already did some troubleshooting. I see "Compressing file data..." and I can write to and read from my files with my functions. The problem lies within zlib_compress.

Comment: @FabianTamp I'm using MinGW 4.4.0. Debugger output above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

char outbuffer[1073741824];

That's too large to put on the stack

Comment: Woah didn't notice that. Lemme make it smaller.

Comment: Although the problem still stands.

Comment: yeah that's a gigabyte. To elaborate a little, if you're getting errors before any code executes in a function, it's probably a memory allocation error.

Comment: I think you might need it on heap seems you are compressing something and need a big buffer

Comment: This problem can be addressed after this though. I do not even reach this function, hence the allocation is never done.

Comment: Stack allocations usually happen before any code executes, especially in optimized code.  It is extremely likely that `outbuffer` is put on the stack immediately on the function call is this saves an instruction and doesn't affect execution.

Comment: Note that typical stack sizes are 1-32 MB, depending both on compiler and compiler options.  You should never use the stack for more than 1k or so of data.

Comment: Never realized that program stacks were that small, although I've never tried to put anything larger that 1KB on it. Tested on VC++2012 at 1MB and Xcode at 8MB with default projects. I think the only time I've suffered stack overflows was with recursive functions. What's interesting with his problem is that he didn't get a stack overflow error, but a seg fault.

Comment: This is the correct answer. CodeBlocks wasn't compiling so I reset it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a constant reference to a string as a parameter in your zlib_compress - you need to make sure that memory is available (whatever is returned from your readfile) in your zlib_compress. It would be good if you can share the prototype of your readFile function too.